# Joining the dataframe to its implicit column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, inner-join

### Input table

[input data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ647.png)

it contains four columns [ id , route , provider , zipcode ]

->id is the unique value

-> route is a driver location which gets updated over period of time and it looks like this

```html
[{'latitude': '40.45591',
  'longitude': '-79.94219',
  'updatedAt': 1667735101102},
 {'latitude': '40.47023',
  'longitude': '-79.92902',
  'updatedAt': 1667738498659},
 {'latitude': '40.47023',
  'longitude': '-79.92902',
  'updatedAt': 1667738661292},
 {'latitude': '40.47023',
  'longitude': '-79.92902',
  'updatedAt': 1667738796658},
 {'latitude': '40.47023',
  'longitude': '-79.92902',
  'updatedAt': 1667738918577},
 {'latitude': '40.47021243896656',
  'longitude': '-79.92899329804723',
  'updatedAt': 1667738992677}]
```

-> I want to map the  corresponding `ids` to  each `lat,lng & updatedat` present to its corresponding route .

[desired op](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qb8a.png)

table can be cloned from here `gh repo clone ajayvd/route-table`

[github link](https://github.com/ajayvd/route-table)

```js
x=df.iloc[0]['ROUTE']
y=df.iloc[0]['_ID']
k=pd.DataFrame(x)
k['orderid']=y
```

let me know how can i approach it ?

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

You can resolve this issue by below code :

```
import pandas as pd
order_df = pd.read_csv('route-table-main/route_table.csv')
main_df = pd.DataFrame()

ID=order_df.to_dict(orient='list')['_ID']
ROUTE= order_df.to_dict(orient='list')['ROUTE']

for order_id,Route in zip(ID,ROUTE):
    ROUTE_LIST = eval(Route)
    route_df = pd.DataFrame(ROUTE_LIST)
    route_df['order_id'] = order_id
    main_df = main_df.append(route_df)
```

**output**

```
    latitude    longitude   updatedAt          order_id
0   40.45591    -79.94219   1667735101102   63676b4a47727e592feb5bcb
1   40.47023    -79.92902   1667738498659   63676b4a47727e592feb5bcb
2   40.47023    -79.92902   1667738661292   63676b4a47727e592feb5bcb
3   40.47023    -79.92902   1667738796658   63676b4a47727e592feb5bcb
4   40.47023    -79.92902   1667738918577   63676b4a47727e592feb5bcb
```

Comment: hey @vipul prajapati , the id's must match up with all the { lat, long &updated at } not only the element present at 0th index .